# Analog input voltage rises when motor is working

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, input, analog

I'm making automatic water plant system. I'm using:

Arduino Uno

3.3-6V water pump -https://www.amazon.com/Vipe-Micro-Submersible-Motor-Water/dp/B01N0X3CW4

Capacitive soil moisture sensor - [https://www.amazon.com/Gikfun-Capacitive-Corrosion-Resistant-Detection/dp/B07H3P1NRM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07H3P1NRM)

I've noticed that when motor turns on sensor readings are much higher. First I thought that the problem is in sensor, but when I measured sensor output in both cases (when motor is on and when motor is off) there was no difference, voltage was the same. Then I measured voltage in analog pin A0 that I used, and I saw there is increase in voltage when pump is on (+0.4V), so my guess is that this voltage is added to  sensor output voltage which is giving me higher values in my serial monitor.

For powering my pump I'm using same circuit as in this example:
https://www.devacron.com/arduino-tip120-control-dc-motor/

Just except potentiometer there is my sensor, powered via 3.3V Arduino pin (its GND is connected to Arduino GND). I also tried connecting all grounds together in one point, didn't help. I powered Arduino with usb and with 9V supply, in both cases same problem. Tried powering pump and Arduino with same and with different power supplies, no luck either.

I should also add that there is no change in AREF and 5V pin when pump is working. 4.97V in both cases.

Does anyone have any idea what can be the problem and how to solve it?

Here is how I wired everything:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IDQR.jpg

I also tried with 0.1uF ceramic and 10nF electrolytic capacitors. as suggested, wiring it like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNQnX.jpg
Didn't make much difference, problem is still there.

Comment: Nothing coming to mind immediately, at least nothing I have good reason to think is actually the problem.  Even with the reference diagram and understanding how you've effectively replaced the potentiometer with the sensor, it would be good to have a picture of the actual wiring.  Sometimes it just reveals things you didn't think to mention.

Comment: My first thought is that you have a noise problem with either the sensor itself picking up noise and misinterpreting it as input or noise being picked up by the analog pin and interfering with your readings.  You might try it without the pump motor hooked up so that you can isolate the problem.

Comment: @jwh20 without the motor, sensor reading are stable when connected to analog pin. Can there be a problem with Arduino? I do not have other just this one, but I don't know what are the chances that something is wrong...I bought it just for this project and I must also add that in this project I had a lot more components connected (I removed everything except pump and sensor to try to isolate the problem, just as you said) and everything else works great, even bme280 sensor and oled display, which are connected to A4 and A5 pins. Maybe is noice from the pump...But I can't remove it completely...

Comment: Why don't you show how you have things hooked up?  I suspect you have either a power supply issue or a noise issue caused by the motor.  You either need to beef up the supply to your motor and/or filter the noise being produced by it.

Comment: @timemage  I will draw what I've done, no problem and edit my main post

Comment: That may help.  But clear actual pictures of real wiring won't hurt.

Comment: @timemage jwh20 I added link in my first post hope it's clear enough

Comment: Try adding some bypass capacitors across the motor leads and also from Vcc to GND at the moisture sensor.

Comment: I have only one thought beyond what jwh20 has said, but it's dependent on your 2.2k resistor not really being 2.2k.

Comment: @timemage  Yes, It is actually a 2k resistor on the picture, not 2.2 you are right, I made I mistake. I'm pretty sure though it's not a current problem. I also tried with higher value resistors, even tried just turning the motor on all the time directly from power source, without that transistor circuit and signal from Arduino, just motor, diode, sensor and Uno, with only grounds connected together and same thing happened. So I hope that  capacitors will solve my problem.

Comment: The diode on your schematic drawing is in the wrong configuration. It supposed to connect across the motor with cathode to 5V and anode to the join of motor and the collector pin of TIP120. See [what is a protection diode](http://learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/What-is-a-protection-diode) for explanation. You get it wrong because the link that you provided has a wrong connection too.

Comment: @hcheung, compare with the image of the actual wiring.  They probably just got it backwards trying to make the diagram quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some bypass capacitors at the two points I've added arrows to:

[image: Bypass Caps]

I suggest two in each spot, one a 0.1uF (or similar) ceramic dipped or disc and the other a 1 or 10uF electrolytic.  Keep the polarity in mind for the electrolytic.

Oh, and another thing.  Be sure your motor is not pulling your power supply voltage down.  It's possible your phone charger supply is inadequate to supply the power needs of the motor.  Use a voltmeter across the input to the Arduino and check the voltage when the motor runs.  If it's dropping much below 5V you need a better power supply.  Well, I see now that you are only powering the motor from that 5V supply.  So that's probably not it.

Comment: Thank you very much for suggestion. Unfortunately, I don't have them right know at my place, but I could get them tomorrow when shops are open, so I will post results then :)

Comment: ok I tried with capacitors, one 0.1uF ceramic, and one 10uF electrolytic where I put longer lead to + side and shorter to -. I can get a picture of my circuit if it's needed if you think I maybe wired it bad. Didn't help. Sensor value in water is 250 and when motor is on, in a few seconds value goes up to 450, then it goes down to 400 in about 30 seconds and that's it...

Comment: Please update your question with a photo of what you've tried.

Comment: ok I added and put a photo hope it's clear enough

Comment: It's clear there is some sort of interference caused by the motor or your motor control circuit that is causing the reading from what I suspect is a very sensitive "antenna" moisture sensor and the caps are just not enough.  How about a different approach?  You might try pumping water for a few seconds and then stopping the pump and taking a series of readings over a few minutes until the values stabilize.  Then repeat as needed until you get to the moisture reading you want.

Comment: I already did that in my code, before even asking this question. I'm reading from sensor every two minutes which is more then enough from values to stabilize, so it's not affecting functionality of my project at all. However, I asked this question because I was pissed that I couldn't find solution. I googled, read many forums, solutions, and nothing worked so I decided to ask here in case that maybe someone would have any new idea. Is it possible that Arduino is faulty? I'm not planning to buy a new one, but I would like to know where the problem is :) Thank you anyways :)

Comment: I doubt the Arduino is defective. These types of issues can be difficult to track down but it's also exacerbated by the way you have constructed this so far, specifically with wires going all over the place being quite long, no shielding, etc.  Since we addressed, to some degree at least, the power, the next is noise being introduced into the analog input line from your sensor.  Don't feel bad about this, you're at the interface between theory and real-world issues.  Noise problems keep engineers up at night!

Comment: This particular sensor just generated an analog signal and the ADC in the Arduino just reads that voltage.  You might also try putting a capacitor, try a smaller one like your 0.1 uF, from that signal line to GND.  That will help to "slow down" the signals on that line.  You not really needing to take readings quickly in this application since you really are not ever changing the moisture content quickly.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions :))